# How to toggle “required/not required” custom customer attribute field?

Tags: magento2, form-validation

Whether the field is invisible/optional/required in the forms should be configurable from the admin side and enforced both client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Many fields are configurable under *Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options*.

Custom customer attributes could use the same pattern, i.e. by using a system.xml to make required fields configurable and overriding form templates accordingly.

Comment: I said custom customer attribute

Answer (score 0):

Stores > Attributes > Customer >

[image: Buttons to route Stores Attributes Customer]

Search for your custom Customer Attribute

For example "middlename"

[image: Search for your custom Customer Attribute For example "middlename"]

Click on the Customer Attribute

Properties > Attribute Properties > Values Required = YES/NO

[image: Properties > Attribute Properties > Values Required]